# immediate Ajax call vs loading more content upfront

Tags: html, node.js, express

I am building a blog that displays content similar to how youTube does. I want to have my blog article in the center and a sidebar on the right. I want the sidebar to contain previews of several other articles that I have written along with their corresponding image (like the youTube layout). At the bottom of the sidebar, I want to have a button to load more content.

I am trying to brainstorm how I should deal with serving the sidebar content. I have thought of two ways of doing it but am not sure how efficient or standard they are. (Also this blog is in express btw)

I can load a set amount of content before my express view is called. For example, I can query my db for 8 article previews and pass that with my view. e.g `res.render("example.ejs", {articleTitles:[], pathToArticleImages:[]}`

I can load my express view without any of the sidebar content and then make an immediate ajax call to get content for the sidebar. e.g `res.render("example.ejs")`

My question is which option seems more optimal? Is it better for the view to take longer to load but all content comes at once vs loading the article right away and then waiting for the sidebar content to arrive via ajax?

If both of my ideas suck, how can this best be accomplished? Thanks :)

Comment: As a user, I would be happy to see the main content faster and wait for the sidebar to be loaded via AJAX. **But** when the sidebar eventually loads it must not disturb the main content in any way (e.g., displace a button on which I was about to click).

Comment: It's a tradeoff between time to display first content, issues with incremental layout in the browser as more content arrives and minimizing http requests to your server.  There is no "right" answer as it really depends on how you prioritize things.  I agree with Heiko that, as a user, I absolutely hate content that displays initially and then moves around as more content arrives making it difficult for you to interact with it until it loads everything.  You can avoid that even with incremental filling of the sidebar as long as the sidebar space is fixed initially.

Comment: Another consideration is what you're doing for small screens and perhaps not loading the sidebar at all (saving bandwidth on phones).  You can make that adjustment either server-side or client-side, but sometimes dynamic size stuff like that is easier on client-side.